# How to force InfoPath 2010 to have content="IE=Edge" in SharePoint

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint-2010, doctype, infopath, x-ua-compatible

We have an InfoPath form published to a SharePoint 2010 library. When we try to open the form it takes ages to load. When the document Mode is changed to IE9 Standards through developer tools and reopen the form it is very quick.

For this reason we need to change the content="IE=Edge" or "IE=9". We also tried making the setting in the masterpage. When we made the change, the page library is upgraded to IE9 Standard where as the Infopath form still remains in IE8.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To change the content mode you have to change the meta tag on the masterpage that I believe you already did. If it is not reflecting on the site make sure that you have checked in the master page after the edition, published the major version and approved it, other wise the change will be only visible for the user that made it.

I should warn you that the SharePoint2010 was designed to work with content="IE=8"

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

If you change it on the masterpage you for IE9 or EDGE you will lose some functionalities like the rich text options on multi-line text box

Comment: Hi Joao, Thanks for the response. Actually the change of "IE=Edge" in masterpage is working for SharePoint 2010 sites except for the InfoPath form. Did not have a observe the multi-line text boxes though. So when we open the InfoPath form and look into the source code it still shows "IE=8".